# Compare 2 string templates

Tags: javascript, string

Let's say I have 3 string templates:

```
A = `
Table <name> {
<attribute-name> <data-type>
}
`
B = `
Table User {
name varchar
}
`
C = `
Table Price {
name
}
`
```

Here, **A** is the template. And I want **B** and **C** to be in the same format as **A**. In the example, **C** does not match, so it will throw an error. Whereas **B** matches.

And I want the placeholders `<name>` or `<data-type>` to map onto their values according to **B**. Here, `<name>` should be "User" and `<attribute-name>` should be "name" and `<data-type>` should be "varchar".

I can do a linear search and compare the strings, but is there any elegant approach to this? or a javascript library?

Comment: I understand. By template, I meant a predefined format. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah, "template" in the general sense. :-) Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the template to a regular expression by replacing `<...>` placeholders with named groups and then match your outputs against it (assuming each a placeholder is equivalent to `\w+`):

```js
function tpl2re(tpl) {
    return new RegExp(tpl.replace(
        /<(.+?)>/g,
        ($0, $1) => '(?<' + $1.replace(/\W/g, '_') + '>\\w+)'
    ))
}

A = `
Table <name> {
<attribute-name> <data-type>
}
`

B = `
Table User {
name varchar
}
`
C = `
Table Price {
name
}
`

re = tpl2re(A)
m = B.match(re); console.log(m && m.groups)
m = C.match(re); console.log(m && m.groups)
```

Comment: I never really worked with regexes before. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an even cleaner approach, but I think a regex here can assist you.

Here's a simple one to match your three placeholders: `/^Table (\w*) {\n(\w*) (\w*)\n}/gm`

```js
B = `
Table User {
name varchar
}
`
C = `
Table Price {
name
}
`

function parseTemplate(str) {
  var regex = /^Table (\w*) {\n(\w*) (\w*)\n}/gm
  var matches = regex.exec(str);
  if (matches && matches.length == 4) {
    return {
      name: matches[1],
      'attribute-name': matches[2],
      'data-type': matches[3]
    };
  } else return null;
}

console.log(parseTemplate(B));
console.log(parseTemplate(C));
```

Comment: Thanks. Both the answers were really helpful.